# Variable used in if statement condition not recognized

Tags: swift

I am trying to write some logic to simplify my code. A variable's value (`pointpb`) is changed based on different inputs and depending on that variable's value, an `if` statement will execute.

I originally had the variable declared inside an `if` statement but quickly changed that once I realized it could not be used outside of that statement. I have used the usual resources. Google, YouTube, and skimmed through Apple's docs, declared the variable in different scopes of the code, etc., but can not seem to find why this is.

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {  
    var pointpb = 0

    //add icon push button action/draw select enable

    @IBAction func Addpointpb(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        pointpb = 1
        Iconselected.textColor = UIColor.blue
        self.Iconselected.text = "Select One"
        self.Circleselect.isHidden = false
        self.Lineselect.isHidden = false
        self.Pointselelct.isHidden = false
    }

    //point selected
    @IBAction func Pointselect(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        pointpb = 2
        self.Pointselelct.isHidden = true
        self.Circleselect.isHidden = true
        self.Lineselect.isHidden = true
        self.Addpointpb.isHidden = true
        self.Pointcancel.isHidden = false
        self.Iconselected.text = "Point"
    }

    //line selected
    @IBAction func Lineselect(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        pointpb = 3
        self.Pointselelct.isHidden = true
        self.Circleselect.isHidden = true
        self.Lineselect.isHidden = true
        self.Addpointpb.isHidden = true
         self.Pointcancel.isHidden = false
        self.Iconselected.text = "Line"
    }

     //circle selected
    @IBAction func Circleselect(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        pointpb = 4
        self.Pointselelct.isHidden = true
        self.Circleselect.isHidden = true
         self.Lineselect.isHidden = true
        self.Addpointpb.isHidden = true
         self.Pointcancel.isHidden = false
        self.Iconselected.text = "Circle"
    }
}

//==================================================================

//preferred code for me to use   

//point selected

@IBAction func Pointselect(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    pointpb = 2
    self.Iconselected.text = "Point"
}

//line selected
@IBAction func Lineselect(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    pointpb = 3
    self.Iconselected.text = "Line"
}

//circle selected
@IBAction func Circleselect(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    pointpb = 4
    self.Iconselected.text = "Circle"
}

//if statement

if pointpb == 2, pointpb == 3, pointpb == 4
{
    self.Pointselelct.isHidden = true
    self.Circleselect.isHidden = true
    self.Lineselect.isHidden = true
    self.Addpointpb.isHidden = true
    self.Pointcancel.isHidden = false
}
```

As you can see, the `UIButton` inputs for the last three functions do essentially the same thing. Ideally I would like to use the section of code at the bottom. However, as previously mentioned, the variable is no longer recognized and I receive an "expected declaration" error pointing to that `if` statement. I feel this is something stupidly obvious but obviously I'm stupid.

Comment: Replace each comma with `||`. And put the if statement in a function.

Comment: You're getting *expected declaration* because your `if` statement needs to be inside of a `func` body.  You can't put code like that at the top level of the `class`.

Comment: @vacawama Thank you for your incredibly quick response. I will try making my own function and adding the if statement there. Once again thank you.

Comment: Make sure you do what rmaddy and Jason suggest as well.  You need those *logical ORs* `||` instead of the commas.

Comment: I will. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're writing your if statement is closer to the syntax for declaring multiple variables at once, hence Xcode says it "expected declaration"

The proper way to write your if clause would be
`if (pointpb == 2 || pointpb == 3 || pointpb == 4)`

Check out the [Swift basics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) to brush up on syntax

Also just as a tip, you can simplify your if clause a bit with `if [2, 3, 4].contains(pointpb)`

Comment: You don’t need the parentheses in the if statement.

Comment: Correct. It's just preference. I left them out in the second if since there's only 1 boolean condition, but added them in the first if since there are multiple boolean conditions

Comment: @Jason Thank you for the tip I will definitely be implementing this.